# Position fields in a form correctly

Tags: html, css

I know this is basic, I've lost hours on this, read posts, books, etc and it doesn't matter: I just don't understand how CSS works...

I want to have field 2) below field 1) in the following form:

```
<label>1) Select date</label>
<p>
    <select name="data" id="data" form="configs">
        <option value="custom">Custom</option>
        <option value="thismonth">This Month</option>
        <option value="lastmonth">Last Month</option>
        <option value="ytd">Year to Date</option>
    </select>
</p>
<div id="frombox">
    <label for="from">From</label>
    <br \>
    <input type="text" class="box" name="from">
</div>
<div id="tobox">
    <label for="to">To</label>
    <br \>
    <input type="text" class="box" name="to">
</div>


<label>2) Select fields to import</label>
<p>
    <input type="text " name="datepicker " id="datepicker " required/>
</p>
```

With the CSS:

```
#frombox {
    float:left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 150px;
}
#tobox {
    float:left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 150px;
}
.box {
    width: 100px;
}
```

You may see a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nuno/nou0qd1j/1/)

Comment: Btw your `<br \>` should be `<br/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/isqware/y3mf4q2j/

```
#frombox {
float:left;
margin-left: 5px;
width: 150px;
}
#tobox {
float:left;
margin-left: 5px;
width: 150px;
clear:both;
}
.box {
width: 100px;
}
label {
clear: both;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code, check the below link http://jsfiddle.net/isqware/y3mf4q2j/4/